# How to add user to a group from Mac OS X command line?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, osx-leopard

I am trying to add a user to a group from the command line but can't figure out how. Specifically this is on Mac OS X **Server** version 10.5.8.

The user is 'john', the groups are 'admin' and 'wheel'.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a john -t user admin
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a john -t user wheel
```

It's also possible to do this with `dscl`, but to do it properly you need to both add the user's short name to the group's `GroupMembership` list, *and* add the user's GeneratedUID to the group's `GroupMembers` list.  `dseditgroup` takes care of both in a single operation.

Comment: Sorry i'm not too cleared with the usage. Lets say i want to add the username `bob` into `wheel`, will it be `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a bob -t user wheel` ?

Comment: @夏期劇場: Correct.

Comment: I had to add `-p` as well so I could enter my password.

Comment: Still valid on osx 10.9.2; copy and paste if you are searching for apache: ```sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a `whoami` -t user _www```

Comment: Still works in 10.10.3 (Yosemite).

Comment: Will these commands affect user's recently groups?

Comment: @Eray I don't understand the question; can you clarify?

Comment: Working in El Capitan (10.11.6) as well!

Comment: This is an excellent resource: https://blog.travismclarke.com/post/osx-cli-group-management/

Comment: Well well. What do you know. It still works under macOS Big Sur 11.0 Beta (20A5384c)! Thanks!

Comment: `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a "$(whoami)" -t user "wheel"`

Answer (score 20):

For those who are looking for the same answer to newer versions of Mac OS, I've found this:
To add a user to a group, you need this command ($USER is the current logged-in user) :

```
$ sudo dscl . append /Groups/wheel GroupMembership $USER
```

I was trying to add my user to the `wheel` group, to be able to manipulate the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder. Besides that, I had to change the permissions to that folder, as by default it is `755`. I've changed it to `775` with:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

This way I can manipulate the folder content without changing the owner of the folder.

*ps. Still working on Catalina (10.15.3)*

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether this works on 10.14 (mojave) ?

Comment: It works for me on 10.14.4.

Comment: Great. works with Mojave 10.14.5. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @GordonDavisson's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/214311) seems also to work on recent versions (I just used it on Ventura), and says that, in addition to this step, one should also add the user's UID to the group's `GroupMembers` list.

Comment: works on macos Ventura 13.5 (well, worked once)

Answer (score 5):

Check out this link:

http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/

> Adding a user is something easily
>   accomplished using the built in GUI
>   tools that ship with OS X, however any
>   power user can appreciate the possible
>   efficiency gained from using the
>   command line. So in the spirit of
>   efficiency here are the steps
>   necessary to add a user to your Mac OS
>   X system all with our good friend,
>   Terminal.app.

The important bit is here:

> Create and set the user’s group ID
>   property.

```
dscl / -create /Users/toddharris PrimaryGroupID 1000
```

Comment: tried it with `sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership username` and though it added the user to "admin" but it also added a bunch of other groups like `com.apple.sharepoint.group.1` and `com.apple.access_screensharing` ect... ?!?

Comment: That is strange. On the other hand, perhaps these are groups that have been associated with that user, or it somehow inherited them from elsewhere.

Comment: Did you read through the `man` pages for `dscl` at all?

Answer (score 0):

on macOS "Sonoma", I added a user to a group with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash -ve

sudo grep admin /etc/sudoers

USER=foo

# add $USER to "admin" group
sudo echo $USER
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a $USER -t user admin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).