# I just installed Apache, MySQL and PHP stack on my Mac but now everytime I alter a file the OS asks me for my system password? How can I stop this?

Tags: apache-http-server, mac, localhost, mamp

I just installed Lion on my machine and I'm starting fresh. I thought I'd manually install an AMP stack on my machine. Also, I'm using my ~/Sites folder as my web root. However, now that everytime I update a file I'm being asked for my system password.

I think it's a permission problem except I'm not entirely sure what to do. Can someone help?

Comment: This may also be better served on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple of things, but the basics will be [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) and [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown). Chmod changes the permissions of the file or folder to allow rights on a user, group, and world access. Chown changes who owns the file or folder.

From the command line you could use `chown -R` to change ownership recursively for all files and subfiles to your username. Or, better yet, you could change the file permissions similarly using `chmod -R`.

In octal notation doing something like `chmod -R 777 ~/Site`s will make it readable, writeable, and executable by everyone on the machine (not necessarily the best way to go). chmod -R 755 would make it writable, executable to the owner and readable by everyone else. There's lots of examples and ways to do this.

You may want to look into [users and groups](https://superuser.com/questions/214004/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-from-mac-os-x-command-line) to avoid making it all world executable, and not annoying you everytime you want to modify a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the folder permissions to 777 from the console:

```
chmod 777 <directory path>
```