# How can I add myself to _www:staff permanently on osx?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, file-permissions, finder

I have a local instance of apache with an application writing to a cache directory. The cache directory is written to by _www:staff. It appears in the finder with a 'no-entry' icon. How can I add my own user to the _www:staff group permanently to prevent this from happening now and in future if I clear the cache? I would like to browse the directory from finder.

OS is OSX Mountain Lion.

I have tried the following:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a myusername -t user _www //i substituted my own username
```

example `ls` output:

```
drwxrwxrwx  234 _www           staff  7956  7 Nov 17:09 .
drwxr-xr-x   17 myusername  staff   578  7 Nov 09:33 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 myusername  staff  6148  7 Nov 09:22 .DS_Store
drwx------    3 _www           staff   102  7 Nov 09:23 spektrix-00
drwx------    3 _www           staff   102  7 Nov 09:23 spektrix-01
drwx------    5 _www           staff   170  7 Nov 09:22 spektrix-02
drwx------    9 _www           staff   306  7 Nov 09:23 spektrix-03
drwx------    6 _www           staff   204  7 Nov 09:23 spektrix-04
drwx------    4 _www           staff   136  7 Nov 09:22 spektrix-05
drwx------    7 _www           staff   238  7 Nov 09:22 spektrix-06
drwx------    4 _www           staff   136  7 Nov 09:22 spektrix-07
drwx------    4 _www           staff   136  7 Nov 08:55 spektrix-08
drwx------    4 _www           staff   136  7 Nov 09:23 spektrix-09
drwx------    4 _www           staff   136  7 Nov 08:55 spektrix-0a
drwx------    3 _www           staff   102  7 Nov 08:54 spektrix-0b
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/214004/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-from-mac-os-x-command-line

Comment: thanks but this did not resolve the issue. Finder still shows the red icon (I rebooted first).

Comment: What does an ls -l of the directory in question show?

Answer (score 1):

As I was beginning to suspect (text conventions are not set in stone, however) - you are already a member of the group, staff.

_www is a different user, also a member of staff.

_www:staff is not a group, it's a user:group designation.

You just need to chmod the directory so that group (staff) has read permissions, where it presently has no permissions. You may even be able to do this from Finder (as with sudo, it will ask for your password) by doing a **Get Info** on the folder and adjusting permissions in the **Sharing and Permissions** box at the bottom (you may need to click the lock icon in the lower right first) and select **Apply to enclosed items** from the "gear" icon near the left.

It can also be done with a **sudo chmod** command, but you may not need it if you can get what you want through Finder.

Assuming they haven't messed about with chmod since 10.7:

**sudo chmod -R g+rx** *directory-name*

should do it.